# Gimme them gold coins

Tags: phrase-meaning

"Gimme" means "give me", so "Gimme them gold coins" means "Give me them gold coins'- here we get both "me" and "them" as objects. Does it mean "Give me gold coins and give them gold coins"?  It is confusing to me.

> Light of my life, fire of my loins
> Be a good baby, do what I want
> Light of my life, fire of my loins
> **Gimme them gold coins**, gimme them coins

> Source: Lyrics   My old man is a bad man

Answer (score 8, accepted):

"Them" is being used instead of "those".

> Gimme them gold coins (dialectal) = Give me those gold coins (standard)

It's used in some dialects, but isn't grammatically correct.

Comment: Exactly.  Very bad grammar; the very essence of *vulgarity* in the literal sense.

Comment: I'm not so certain that this usage isn't consistent enough to be considered a dialect in its own right. It's not "correct" in _standard English_, but I would be surprised to hear "those" in AAVE.